# How to store JSON response in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, save, response

I'd like to store my json response in a global variable so, i could use it through my app without making a getJSON request more than once.

```
var data;
$.getJSON("panorama.json",function(json){
data = json.images[0].src;
console.log(data);          
});


console.log(data);
```

If I log it in the actual request its fine, but i get "undefined" everywhere else.
Any comment appriciated.

Edit [copied from comments]:  Tried ...

```
$.myglobals = { result: "unset" } 

$(document).ready(function() { 

  $.getJSON( "panorama.json", function(json) { 
    $.myglobals.result = json.images[0].src; 
    console.log($.myglobals.result);     
  });

  console.log($.myglobals.result); 
}) ;
```

The first log is okay, the second is undefined.

Edit [copied from answer]:

> actually both method worked
>
> the interesting thing is that my
>   request was in a function and i tried
>   to acces my global variable right
>   after the request in the same function
>
> when i accesed it outside the function
>   it worked like a charm

Comment: I wonder if you were accessing your global variable before it got updated?  From  the JQuery example: Note: Keep in mind, that lines after this function will be executed before callback.

Comment: you might be right about the updating, but how exactly could i tell if my global var has been updated? or where shall i put my request so that my global var is updated before i use it, the only thing i can think of is writing everything in the request's callback but that sounds silly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your real code is structured like that then you have a problem with trying to access the data that hasn't been set **yet**. Just because your `$.getJSON()` is above `console.log()` doesn't mean that you get the response before you log value of data.

So your problem is not scope, but rather the timing: introduce some server-side lag and your solution may as well crash.

Maybe you should set some flag if response was received:

```
var data, dataReceived = false;

$.getJSON("panorama.json",function(json){
  data = json.images[0].src;
  dataReceived = true;
  console.log(data);                    
});


// somwhere later
if (dataReceived) {
  console.log(data);
} else {
  // you could use setTimeout() or setInterval here to re-check
  console.log("data not received yet");
}
```

Comment: actually both method worked the interesting thing is that my request was in a function and i tried to acces my global variable right after the request in the same function when i accesed it outside the function it worked like a charm thanks both of you

Comment: @soda1, the convention at StackOverflow is to update your original question, rather than post an answer.

Comment: yeah i figured it is a timing problem eventually. just implemented it using a flag and a setInterval on the checking, and it works okay

Answer (score 1):

You could insert it into an attribute in the DOM (such as an #ID) and retrieve it as needed.

Comment: i guess it'd be okay if it was a simple string but actually its a huge json object

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that lets you set the variable in one $(document).ready() and use it in a different $(document).ready().  `myglobals` is a namespace object which arguably reduces the chances of your global variable colliding with someone else's, especially if you name it something more clever than "myglobals."

```
$.myglobals = {
  result: "unset" 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  function pretend_JSON_call() {
    $.myglobals.result = {'a':"hello", 'b':"world" };
  }

  pretend_JSON_call();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($.myglobals.result['a']);
  alert($.myglobals.result['b']);
});
```

[Transient link](http://jsbin.com/ikoqi/edit) to the above code in jsbin.

Comment: $.myglobals = {
  result: "unset" 
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("panorama.json",function(json){
                 $.myglobals.result = json.images[0].src;
    console.log($.myglobals.result);   
});
      console.log($.myglobals.result);

})

the first log is ok, but the second is still undefined

Comment: sorry for the unstyled comment i'm kinda new around here

Comment: @soda01, I copied the source in your comment to your question so that it will format nicely.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON fires an ajax request (the keyword in the scope of the question being asynchronous).Your variable is undefined because it hasn't been define yet, the response hasn't finished. Other people suggested moving your console.log further down in your code, but there's no guarantee it will be usable unless your logic is synced with a callback function.  $.getJSON accepts a callback function as one of its parameters.

```
$.getJSON( "myData.json", function( data ) {
    //Do whatever, this is a callback
    $.each( data, function(key, val) {
       //You can get even more specific like so
    });
});
```