# Push an API query result (JSON) in firebase

Tags: json, firebase

Complete noob here. I was trying to do a simple task and I seem unable to do what I want no matter how I try.

I would like to query an API (ex: http://api.feathercoin.com/?output=usd&amount=1&json=1) and put the query result in a Firebase entry each time I load my page.
I've gone through the tutorial and thought it may be easy but... I was wrong.

I see for example in the REST API examples [page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html) that:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }' \
https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/jack/name.json
```

but I don't have a clue about how to add this in my html file.
Something very similar has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458153/importing-json-string-to-firebase-domain) but the answer seems worst than the question.

Any hint?
Thx

EDIT:

looking around stackoverflow I ended up with this non functioning script:

```
var ftcjson={};
$.getJSON('http://voingiappone.altervista.org/ftc.json', function(data) { 
ftcjson=data;
}); 

var x = ftcjson.gbp;
alert(x);
```

I should get the gbp value as a response but I get "undefined". No matter what I do. 
To read an off site json file and store it in a variable seems an impossible task while I'm sure it is really easy.

Help please.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use the REST API from an HTML page? What is the use case for not using the [JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html)?

Comment: @Kato I moved a little on from here. As you say I cannot use the REST API and started using jquery. Looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1020166/3420983) it appears that I can assign a JSON to a variable. The problem is that when I try to access the variable itself I get "xxx is not defined". Any hint?